# Destructure multiple keys to the same variable name

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I get a response from multiple APIs with relatively the same object structure but key names might vary as example:

```
response1 = {name:"Something", image:"path_to_image", ...}
response2 = {title:"Something", image:"path_to_image", ...}
response3 = {label:"Something", image:"path_to_image", ...}
```

I want to destructure those objects to the same variable name:

```
const {name|title|label: title, ...rest} = response
```

in order to use it in the component without the need for multiple checks for object keys like this as example:

```
const title = response?.title || response?.name || response?.label;
```

Can it be done with destructure directly or any one line solution?

Comment: What if the response object has two or more of those properties?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it can't, just the name might be something else, as most teams don't follow the same naming conventions .. they tend to throw a random field name for the same thing like title, label, style, name, etc. and return it directly as a response.

Comment: @SherifSalah You know that for your specific use case, but the writers of ECMAScript can't guarantee that across the all of the objects created so far or that will be created, so they didn't allow that in the language. You're going to have to keep those typing fingers limber after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something weird with default initialisers:

```
const {name, label=name, title=label, ...rest} = response;
// or
const {name, label, title = name ?? label, ...rest} = response;
```

Notice however that this will also declare the variables `name` and `label`. Your one-line solution is much cleaner and better to understand:

```
const title = response.title ?? response.name ?? response.label;
```

---

Alternatively, if you really have a lot of properties, you might want to loop:

```
const key = ['name', 'title', 'label', 'subject', 'content', 'body'].find(key => key in response);
const {[key]: title, ...rest} = response;
```

Comment: After testing this `const {name, label, title = name ?? label, ...rest} = response;` it kinda works! but it somehow has to be ordered from the last declared one first! like this `const {name, label, title = label ?? name, ...rest} = response;` label before name don't know why but it works .. the only downfall and not yours is declaring unused variables

Comment: @SherifSalah I cannot reproduce your issue with swapping `label` and `name`. What would not work is using a variable before it was assigned, like `const {title = label ?? name, label, name, ...rest} = response;`, due to the temporal dead zone. (And no, we're not declaring unused variables, since they are used in the initialisation of `title`)

Comment: I made this based on you suggestion `const {title, image} = {title: response[['name', 'title', 'label', 'subject', 'content', 'body'].find(key => key in response)], ...response}` can you please updated your answer to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `reduce` with a list of expected keys would allow you to find the first of any used.  This makes it dynamic over the `foo.title ?? foo.name`... type approach, which might be useful.

You could of course wrap this into a function for reuse, and to make it a one liner that is self-describing.

```js
response1 = {name:"Something name", image:"path_to_image", }
response2 = {title:"Something title", image:"path_to_image", }
response3 = {label:"Something label", image:"path_to_image", }

const result = [ response1, response2, response3 ].map(response => {
    return {
        name: [ 'name', 'title', 'label' ].reduce((acc, key) => acc ?? response[key], undefined),
        image: response.image,
    }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is really interesting concept and could be easily made as a one like solution like this `const {title, image} = [ {name:"Something", image:"path_to_image"} ].map(response =>  ({title: [ 'name', 'title', 'label' ].reduce((acc, key) => acc ?? response[key], undefined), ...response})).pop()`

Comment: The `reduce` does some unnecessary work by always traversing the full array. You might prefer  `response[ ['name', 'title', 'label'].find(key => key in response) ]`

Comment: @Bergi I used this answer in the comment section and it is awesome, exactly what i was looking for! .. adapted it to Dave's first idea as well, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a simple destructuring technique available. At least I can't think of any.

```js
const arr=[
 {name: "Something1", image:"path_to_image1",xtra:"property"},
 {title:"Something2", image:"path_to_image2",something:"else"},
 {label:"Something3", image:"path_to_image3",here:"too"}];
 
const res=arr.map(o=>{
 let t=o.name||o.title||o.label;
 t={name:t, ...o};
 delete t.title;
 delete t.label;
 return t;
})
console.log(res);
```